# Automatically reject the document if it is rejected by any participant in SPD?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, approval

How do I set an "Automatically reject the document if it is rejected by any participant." if creating a workflow in Sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to do the following:**

- In your `Start Approval Process` Action

  ```
  Start Approval process on Current Item with Hamza Qassas; Mohamed El-Qassas
  ```
- Click on `Approval` word in your action.
- In `Customization` section,> Click on `Change the behavior of a single Task`.

[image]

- At `When a task completes` stage, add `Set Workflow variable` to set `CancelonRejection` to yes

  ```
  Set Variable: CancelonRejection to Yes
  ```
- At else, add `Stop the workflow and log this message`

[image]

- Save & Publish.

Comment: @HatimEzzaki Glad to hear that, Please don't forget to set the answer as accepted, it's the true sign besides my answer!